# Changing a 3 gang Australian light switch to a Smart switch

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I am wanting to change the older style Australian 3 gang light switch with a new ‘Smart’ wifi 3 gang switch.

I just need some help in getting the wiring in the right place.  I have included pictures of the old and new switches.

Any help would appreciated.

Existing switch and wiring
[image]

New switch
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: you're going to need a neutral connection to make that smart switch work.  look in the back of the box for a black wire.

Comment: From what I see it looks like the box only has switch loops, so you're going to need to run a neutral from the nearest  light fitting to the switch box. (that will be the black wire on the light fitting) what's above the ceiling?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your switch is wired using the '3 plate' or 'switch loop' method, so you don't have a neutral available at the switch.

You will need to either get a switch that doesn't require a neutral, or run a new cable to the light that the feed comes from - the two core cable.

Answer (score -1):

The way the 3 gang switch (3 way) has been wired in the picture above is not the correct way to do it as in this configuration, which is "Power to the light", you should have a seperate cable with two wires for each switch.

The Common terminal "C" being the being the permanent live wire and the one terminal "1"  being the switched live wire.

In regards to wiring the Wifi switch you can't do it with this as only the "Active" wires, the permanent live and the switched live, go to the switches
for this switch to work you need a neutral and an earth wire.

http://lrd.kangan.edu.au/electrotech/toolbox1204/resources/04diagrams/04lighting/05loops.htm

Comment: That is perfectly legal practice, if uncommon. There is no requirement for C & 1 to be used in that order, and supply and switched lines being in different cables is acceptable - why else would SDI (single-core double insulated) cable exist?

Comment: The problem here is that the one wire on the first switch ,that is shared across the common terminals, is carrying the load of three lights when all the switches are turned on. This is not the way you want to do it and it makes no sense as you have to pull a cable through anyway why not just use 2 core wire cable for each switch in the first place?  You use the C terminal as permanent live as it is not switched only the 1  & 2 terminals are switched on Australian switches.

Comment: They're all on the same circuit, so it doesn't matter if all the load is down one cable - it's all down one cable if you use a conventional power-to-the-switch method, and it's all down one cable where it leaves the breaker. Four cores to the switch is less copper than six. As for C/1/2, you fundamentally misunderstand how a switch works.

Comment: http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/Electrician/images/BackOfSwMech.gif

Comment: Have you not yet worked out that the voltage drop is still better than doing it the conventional way of power to the switch first (as the neutrals do not have to go via the switch box), and that it's the same as using a 3C cable with one feed and two switch lines?

Comment: "It's not what I'm used to" does not mean "it's wrong".

Comment: I'm not sure how you think this is wired, because it would have to be some form of power to the light (or a junction box). They've just used one light as a junction box for two other strings, requiring four cores.

Comment: It could be back to a junction box, at which point all three switched lines go out to lights. Personally I don't really like 3rd terminal at all unless it goes back to something like a switchboard where it's obvious. Otherwise, who knows which light you need to open up.